# if-Structure Question with multiple conditions

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The manual didn't help me as a Newbie in Pine (and generally only a semi-professional) coder.

In MT4 I would code like this:

```
double MyFirstValue = 1;
double MySecondValue =1;
bool BothValuesNegative = false;

if (MyFirstValue < 0 && MySecondValue < 0)
    BothValuesNegative = true;
```

How is the Syntax in Pine? Can somebody point me in the proper direction, or give a quick example, maybe it should be coded totally different?

Tried to find the answer in the manual, but not in a way that I could grasp it.

One attempt like this, but the plotfunction won't call from there:

```
if (MyFirstValue < 0)
    if(MySecondValue < 0)
    //DrawDownArrow = true
    plotarrow(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `and` in your if statement to combine multiple conditions and then use the reassignment operator `:=` to turn the DrawDownArrow to true.

The `plotarrow` then plots a down arrow if a value is -1 or up arrow if it is 1. Depending on what you're trying to do you can change the 0 to 1 if you want up arrows drawn too, as is will only draw down arrows.

```
DrawDownArrow = false
MyFirstValue = 0
MySecondValue = 0

if MyFirstValue <= 0 and MySecondValue <= 0
    DrawDownArrow := true

plotarrow(DrawDownArrow ? -1  : 0)
```